# Is it possible to build object that respond to the [] operator

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was loading with a library called [D3](https://d3js.org) some CSV file, and doing a `console.log` of the data it returned after it loaded the file, it gave me this result:

```
d3.csv(..., function(data) {
    console.log(data)
    // this returns the following:
    //"(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, columns: Array(8)]"
})
```

Now this part is what is weird to me:

```
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, columns: Array(8)]
```

This looks like a mixture of an array (because I can do something like `var a = data[2]`) but it also looks like an object (because I can do somehting like `var a = data.columns`.

When I do `typeof(data)` I get that it is an object, but I have no idea how to build an object that also responds to the `[]` syntax. (Or an array, that responds to object attributes)

How does such an structure get built?

Comment: `yourArray.yourProp = "xyz";` Arrays are regular Objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are just a type of object. They can do anything an object can do.

```js
var data = ["a", "b", "c"];
data.arbitaryProperty = "Hello, world";
console.log(typeof data);
console.log(data[0]);
console.log(data.arbitaryProperty);
```

Comment: I didnt know that I could set attributes for arrays, wow. Simple and clear explanation, thank you!

PS: can I do it the other way around? Start with an object and then give it array items?

Answer (score 1):

The data returned by `d3.csv()` is, indeed, an array. Not getting into the technical discussion that in JavaScript arrays are objects, what you're seeing is simply an array's property.

For instance, let's see this simple array:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

If I do:

```
arr.foo = "bar";
```

It sets a property to that array. Let's see:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
arr.foo = "bar";
console.log(arr.foo)
```

#### The 'columns' property

In D3 v4, the `d3.csv()` function adds a new property to the array, called `columns`. According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv/blob/master/README.md#csvParse):

> The returned array also exposes a columns property containing the column names in input order (in contrast to Object.keys, whose iteration order is arbitrary).

So, let's load a very small sample CSV which I found online:

```js
d3.csv("https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SVU13_7.2.1/com.ibm.ismsaas.doc/reference/AssetsImportMinimumSample.csv?view=kc", function(data) {
  console.log(data);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

If I use `data.columns` I'll get the array property containing the first row (headers) in that CSV. Let's see the headers:

```js
d3.csv("https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SVU13_7.2.1/com.ibm.ismsaas.doc/reference/AssetsImportMinimumSample.csv?view=kc", function(data) {
  console.log(data.columns);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```